# Chinese shipping culture has a very unique way to name after their cp and sometimes it's hard to translate

Tags: translation

What is 随俞而安 if we translate it to English?

I've tried so many app to translate it but not yet satisfied with the result, maybe there is a native Chinese here that could help me translating that cp's name

the man has 俞 as his surname but the woman's name doesn't include any of those word as her name so i think this cp name has interesting meaning.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[随遇而安](https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E9%9A%8F%E9%81%87%E8%80%8C%E5%AE%89) is an idiom. People just use it for wordplay on 俞更寅 and Amber.  The actual meaning of this idiom "happy-go-lucky" is irrelevant in the wordplay

- The pinyin of 遇/yú/ and 俞/yù/ are similar
- Amber (meaning 琥珀) can be transliterated as 安珀 /Ān Pò/

You can translate '随俞而安' as '**Yu** and **An**' (**俞**更寅 and **Am**ber)

Comment: The pinyin for 遇 is /yù/ but it doesn't really matter. It can be used for wordplay as long as the letters are the same.